# How to analyse multiple choice and overlapping questions in MCA?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, survey, correspondence-analysis, overlapping-data

I need to analyze a survey about entrepreneurship which has around 50 categorical variables.

Therefore, after some univariate analysis, I want to apply Multiple Correspondence Analysis (MCA) in order to reduce dimension. So far, I have seen the videos about MCA from https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLnZgp6epRBbTsZEFXi_p6W48HhNyqwxIu and read some sections from  *Exploratory Multivariate Analysis by Example Using R* book.

My questions regarding MCA are:

- Is it necessary to fully understand CA first?
- How do I work with multiple choice questions? (Should I create binary variables? Or Should I count how many categories each individual marked?)
- For overlapping questions (To answer question "B", the respondent had to answer "Yes" for question "A". Those who have answered "No" to question "A", should I put "No" in "B"?)
- Is it a good idea to make questionnaires with multiple choice or overlapping questions? (It seems that it is not, because book examples don't bring this kind of questions).